# Adding Checks in php for database submit

Tags: php, mysql, database, input

Edit:
I got it up and working for empty check & Number can't start with Zero check
Here how I did it:

```
//Empty Check:
if (empty($_POST["number"])) {
    $numberErr = "Number can't be empty";
  } else {
    $number = test_input($_POST["number"]);
         }

//Zero Check
$zero = substr($number,0,1);
    if ($zero === "0") {
    $zeroErr = "Number can't start with 0";
```

and this code to submit to database:

```
if (empty($_POST["number"])) {
    $numberErr = "Number can't be empty";
} elseif ($zero === "0") {
    $zeroErr = "Number can't start with 0";
} else {
    $number = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "alert('!Added');\n";
    echo "</script>";
    exit;
```

The only downside in this is I have to declare variables twice, one before the form tag (because errors appear in the form) and one right before submitting to database (to meet the conditions), strangely the number is added successfully to the database, but  if I echo number at the end, it appears as (1)!, why is that?, and is there a better way to do this?

As for "if exists check":
mysqli_num_rows was returing an error, after I got it to work, the code ignord my rules about empty check and zero check and inserted anything not duplicated in database!, sry I have no code for what I did, I deleted in a moment of anger :)

---

I've made a form to gather phone numbers only and I've tried to add some functionality and I’ve failed, could use your help..

The php code for database submission as follow:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","PW");
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$number = mysql_escape_string($_POST['number']);

mysql_select_db("wa_phones", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO phone (number)
VALUES 
('$number')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con);
header("Location: done.html");
```

I need to add php check for duplicate in database before submit and a check for empty entry and a check to not allow "0" as the frest number ...

I tried a lot of examples here and there but I couldent make it work with the code I already have

thanks for the help

Comment: Could you show us what you already tried, and why it didn't work?

Comment: *"I tried a lot of examples here and there but I couldent make it work with the code I already have"* - Which is? I don't see code related to checking for duplicates. You could use `mysql_num_rows()` or set your column(s) as `UNIQUE`

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to solve the following problems:

**Validate the phone number**

```
if( ! strlen($number) ) {
    // Phone number is empty.
}
else if( substr($number,0,1) == "0" ) {
    // First digit of phone number is 0.
}
```

**Check to see if it is already in the database**

```
$phone_check_sql = "SELECT number FROM phone WHERE number = '$number'LIMIT 1";
$phone_check_result = mysql_query($phone_check_sql) || die("Some error: ".mysql_error());
if( mysql_num_rows($phone_check_result) != 0 ) {
    // Number already exists.
}
```

You can handle the error however you'd like in those conditional blocks.

Comment: A correction: `else if( substr($number,0,1) === "0" ) {` am working on it, I'll post it here when done so other may use it